# Create a model method that counts a user's posts and test in rspec (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to create a model method that counts the number of posts for a user, and then test it with Rspec.

But I'm running into an error,

```
undefined method `count_posts' for #<User:0x000000044d42a8>
```

**User Model**

```
has_many :posts

def self.count_posts
  self.posts.all.count
end
```

**Posts Model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**User_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe "count_posts" do

      before do
          @user1 = create(:user)
          post = create(:post, user: @user1)
      end

      it "Returns number of posts for a user" do
        expect( @user1.count_posts ).to eq(1)
      end
  end
end
```

**/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email, 100) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com"}
    password "helloworld"
    password_confirmation "helloworld"
  end
end
```

**/factories/posts.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title "Post Title"
    body "Post bodies must be pretty long."
    user
  end
end
```

I don't understand why its an undefined method, unless I've written it incorrectly in the model (which I fully accept as possible).

Apologies in advance if this question is too newbish. But I haven't fully grasped Rspec testing or the use of `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic, `count_posts` must be an instance method instead of class method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def count_posts
    posts.count # or posts.size
  end
end
```